# Where can I buy a tank trap?

Tags: tanks, defense

Where could one procure a full size tank trap?  I am looking for a reproduction of a full size hedgehog style tank trap meeting whatever specs exist for that sort of thing.

Comment: There were a variety of tank traps, what kind were you thinking of?

Comment: I think your best bet is to find accurate drawings and to order them from a metalworking company. That will be expensive, and once they unload them in your driveway you will have trouble moving them ...

Comment: I don't think this can be answered through the use of historical sources and methods. This may not be in scope for H:SE

Answer (score 5):

Historically, some of the most common passive tank defenses were ditches. Other than that there were concrete [pillars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon%27s_teeth_(fortification)) and steel [hedgehogs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czech_hedgehog). Old [manuals](https://usacac.army.mil/sites/default/files/documents/carl/wwIIspec/number15.pdf) can show the specifics.